# AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I got the following list of lists from parsing with Bs4 through the snippet:

```
details = [i.find_all('span', {'class':re.compile('item')}) for i in cars]
```

```
[[<span class="item">Red <small>col.</small></span>,
  <span class="item">120 <small>cc.</small></span>,
  <span class="item">Available <small>in four days</small></span>,
  <span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight-red">15 min</small></span>],
 [<span class="item">Blue <small>col.</small></span>,
  <span class="item">200 <small>cc.</small></span>,
  <span class="item">Available <small>in a week</small></span>,
  <span class="item">04 mar <small></small></span>],
 [<span class="item">Green <small>col.</small></span>,
  <span class="item">Available <small>immediately</small></span>,
  <span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight-red">2 hours</small></span>]]
```

The point is that not every nested list has exactly the same content nor the same length, so I don't want to simplify getting the text in a sole list.

I've tried this code:

```
bobo = []
for detail in details:
    for i in detail:
        bobo.append(i.text)
```

But as I told it yields the following output:

```
[Red col., 120 cc., Available in four days, 15 min., Blue col., 200 cc., Available in a week, 04 mar , Green col., Available immediately, 2 hours]
```

While the expected ouput is:

```
[[Red col., 120 cc., Available in four days, 15 min.],
[Blue col., 200 cc., Available in a week, 04 mar ],
[Green col., Available immediately, 2 hours]]
```

Any help?

Comment: Is this ok? [i.text for i in cars]. You should also post the source HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
bobo = []
for detail in details:
    result = []
    for i in detail:
        result.append(i.text)
    bobo.append(result)
```