# Read CSV file with BeautifulSoup

Tags: list, beautifulsoup, scrape

After scrape some info in a web site I got to save the file with the raw code in html format because I didn't arrive to a solution to `find_all` the text in a list of lists.

Now I have the data but I can't get the text because `bs4` don't recognize the format list.
Here's my open code:

```
with open('/my_file.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)
    print(list_of_rows)
```

This is the list format:

```
[['', '0', '1', '2', '3'], ['0','<span class="item">Red <small>col.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">120 <small>cc.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">Available <small>in four days</small></span>',
  '<span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight-red">15 min</small></span>'],
 ['1', '<span class="item">Blue <small>col.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">200 <small>cc.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">Available <small>in a week</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">04 mar <small></small></span>'],
 ['0', '<span class="item">Green <small>col.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">Available <small>immediately</small></span>',
  '<span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight-red">2 hours</small></span>']]
```

Is there a way to read `csv` files in BeautifulSoup an then parse it?

The aim of the task is to keep only the text, removing everithing between `'<>'` (<> symbols included).

Comment: when you are scrape data and writing in CSV file that time extract only text and put in CSV, not all Html tags.

Comment: :) I know but I had to keep on working until you gave the solution in my last question and the timeline matters. Do you know any way to solve it?

Comment: you can read CSV, and split a string of list and get data which you want. nut it's not a good way to do. what is your last question? nobody helps you without more information.

Comment: In this one you gave the solution:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592456/attributeerror-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-get-text-youre-probably-tr)
That's what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function that will apply the beautifulsoup object and return the text. if there are not tags/content to parse, it'll just leave as is.

Also, I'd rather just use pandas to read in that csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_csv('/my_file.csv')

def foo_bar(x):
    try:
        return BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml').text
    except:
        return x

print ('Parsing html in table...')
df = df.applymap(foo_bar)
```

**Example input:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['0','<span class="item">Red <small>col.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">120 <small>cc.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">Available <small>in four days</small></span>',
  '<span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight-red">15 min</small></span>'],
 ['1', '<span class="item">Blue <small>col.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">200 <small>cc.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">Available <small>in a week</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">04 mar <small></small></span>'],
 ['0', '<span class="item">Green <small>col.</small></span>',
  '<span class="item">Available <small>immediately</small></span>',
  '<span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight-red">2 hours</small></span>']], columns = ['', '0', '1', '2', '3'])
```

**Original table:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                                                      0                                                  1                                                  2                                                  3
0  0  <span class="item">Red <small>col.</small></span>   <span class="item">120 <small>cc.</small></span>  <span class="item">Available <small>in four da...  <span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight...
1  1  <span class="item">Blue <small>col.</small></s...   <span class="item">200 <small>cc.</small></span>  <span class="item">Available <small>in a week<...   <span class="item">04 mar <small></small></span>
2  0  <span class="item">Green <small>col.</small></...  <span class="item">Available <small>immediatel...  <span class="item"><small class="txt-highlight...                                               None
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
               0                      1                       2        3
0  0    Red col.                120 cc.  Available in four days   15 min
1  1   Blue col.                200 cc.     Available in a week  04 mar 
2  0  Green col.  Available immediately                 2 hours     None
```